# Saving output in ArcPy For-Loop?

Tags: arcpy, kernel-density, save, for-loop

How can I save the output of my For loop so that I have a different output name each time?

This is the code I´m using:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
env.workspace = r'C:\Users\lhark\Desktop\SHK\ArcGis_Proj_Canada\shapefiles'
outworkspace = r'C:\Users\lhark\Desktop\SHK\ArcGis_Proj_Canada\KernelDensity'    
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses ()
for fc in fcList:
    outKDens = KernelDensity(fc,"NONE",4670)
```

Comment: Thanks for editing. I am new to this site. Can you tell me how i can formate the code like you did for me or where i can get information on how to do this?

Comment: Just highlight the code and click the format button ({}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListFeatureClasses returns a list of strings, each string is a name (filename) of the FeatureClasses found in your workspace directory. Now KernelDensity returns a raster object that can be saved to disk with the methode save().

What i would now is name the Rasters to the feature class name extended by "_kd" like here:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import os
env.workspace = r'C:\Users\lhark\Desktop\SHK\ArcGis_Proj_Canada\shapefiles'
outworkspace = r'C:\Users\lhark\Desktop\SHK\ArcGis_Proj_Canada\KernelDensity'    
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses ()
for fc in fcList:
    outKDens = KernelDensity(fc,"NONE",4670)
    outKDens.save(outworkspace + "/" + os.path.splitext(fc)[0] + "_kd")
```

If you like to save your output to geotiff (can handle long filenames!), use this extension explicitly:

```
    outKDens.save(outworkspace + "/" + os.path.splitext(fc)[0] + "_kd.tif")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the help file for the [Kernel Density](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/kernel-density.htm) tool, at the bottom is a code sample showing you how to save a raster with a different name.